# How can this permanent table be made temporary?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, temp-tables, mysql-5.7

I need to make the following permanent MySQL table temporary to avoid polluting the DB with tables like FINAL_RESULTS, which I use elsewhere in the query but do not want to persist.

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_RESULTS(
ID VARCHAR(38),
DATE1 DATETIME,
DATE2 DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,DATE1)
);

INSERT INTO FINAL_RESULTS(DATE1,DATE2)
SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID,DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S"))
FROM SOURCE1 AS t1
INNER JOIN SOURCE2 AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.code IN ("a", "b")
AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) <= t2.DATE3
AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) >= t2.DATE4;

UPDATE FINAL_RESULTS
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2.PAT_ID, MIN(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S"))) AS mindate
    FROM SOURCE1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN FINAL_RESULTS AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE t1.CODE IN ("c", "d")
    AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) >= DATE_SUB(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 21 DAY)
    AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) <= DATE_ADD(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    GROUP BY t1.ID
) AS x ON FINAL_RESULTS.ID = x.ID
SET DATE2=x.mindate;
```

**The problem**: if I simply use "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" here instead of "CREATE TABLE", I will get the "Can't reopen table 'FINAL_RESULTS'" error since MySQL only lets you refer to temporary tables once per query, which the last statement violates. The docs recommend using a common table expression to get around this, but I'm running **MySQL 5.7.12** and CTEs only work in version 8.0.

Does anyone have any alternative solutions for version 5.7.12?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create temptable. Then create another temptable using your subquery. Finally update first temptable while joining second one instead of subquery.

Comment: PS. Your `INSERT INTO` is exteremely strange. You insert `t2.ID` into `FINAL_RESULTS.DATE1`...

Comment: Or just upgrade to MySQL 8.0. You should already be planning to do that, because MySQL 5.7 will reach its end of support later this year.

Comment: @Akina, thanks, but I don't think that solves the problem since I would have to put the lines 
`AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) >= DATE_SUB(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 21 DAY)
    AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) <= DATE_ADD(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 14 DAY)` in a subquery in the final join you describe. Perhaps you could share a fixed version of my above SQL in case I have misunderstood you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FINAL_RESULTS(
ID VARCHAR(38),
DATE1 DATETIME,
DATE2 DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,DATE1)
);

INSERT INTO FINAL_RESULTS(DATE1,DATE2) -- ??? should be FINAL_RESULTS(ID, DATE1) ?
SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID,DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S"))
FROM SOURCE1 AS t1
INNER JOIN SOURCE2 AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.code IN ("a", "b")
AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) <= t2.DATE3
AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) >= t2.DATE4;

-- convert the subquery to second temptable
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x
    SELECT t2.PAT_ID, -- ??? should be `AS id` ?
           MIN(DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S"))) AS mindate
    FROM SOURCE1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN FINAL_RESULTS AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE t1.CODE IN ("c", "d")
    AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) >= DATE_SUB(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 21 DAY)
    AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(t1.dateevent,"%d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")) <= DATE_ADD(t2.DATE1, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    GROUP BY t1.ID;

-- use second tempotable instead of the subquery
UPDATE FINAL_RESULTS
INNER JOIN x ON FINAL_RESULTS.ID = x.ID
SET DATE2=x.mindate;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Akina! I see what you mean now :)